# How to get "Document status" data through REST API with Apache ManifoldCF

Tags: rest, document, status, manifoldcf

We're using Apache ManifoldCF. In Admin UI there's report at Status Reports -> Document Status.

Is it possible to get that content through ManifoldCF's [Restful API](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/trunk/en_US/programmatic-operation.html)?

The closest thing I've found is org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.RunDocumentStatus under [Control via Commands](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/trunk/en_US/programmatic-operation.html#Control+via+Commands) but I haven't been able to figure out if that can be used through HTTP API (instead of direct Java code)

Answer (score 0):

No, currently you cant if you are looking to find a status of a single document. but if you want to get the status of queue for a connection you can using

> repositoryconnectionquery/< encoded_connection_name >.